# Laravel - query data from mysql between dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel-5

I am having an issue getting rows from my table using the below query, the expected behaviour is:

user selects start/end date in a form, hits submit and the data passes to the function & it is then used in the query.

The data from the form is coming in fine & I have verifed the dates are coming into the query, but for some reason the query always returns zero results? When I strip out the WHERE statement for the dates, the query works fine & produces results, so the issue is to do with the dates.

```
$fromDate = $request->fromDate;
$toDate = $request->toDate;

$data = cc_table::all('*')
    ->where('link', '1')
    ->where('created_at', '>', $fromDate)
    ->where('created_at', '<', $toDate)
    ->toArray();
```

The dates from the form are formatted as dd/mm/yyyy, and the created_at date is a timestamp, however for testing I did change the created_at to be DATE (dd/mm/yyyy) however the query still returns zero rows.

FYI - I am just using jquery datepicker on my form:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: why not use yyyy-mm-dd all the way through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with this:

```
$fromDate = Carbon::parse($request->input('fromDate'))->format('Y-m-d');
$toDate = Carbon::parse($request->input('toDate'))->format('Y-m-d');
$date_range = [$fromDate . ' 00:00:00', $toDate . ' 23:59:59'];

$data = cc_table::where('link', '1')
->whereBetween('created_at', $date_range)
->get();
```

The format of `$date_range` will depend on the type of your MySQL column.

Note: be sure to `use Carbon\Carbon;` at the top of the script with the above code snippet.

Comment: That is brilliant and worked perfectly, thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Also, thanks for the 'whereBetween' - I overlooked this on the laravel Docs. thanks